# How to load and run different xib file from main.xib in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have one MainWindow.xib file. I have one label and one button on first MainWindow.xib file screen. I have secondview.xib file, i want to load secondview.xib file if user will click on main screen button. I have written a method to load Secondview by the following code..

```
self.second=[[[SecondWindow alloc]initWithNibName:@" HarbourFront" bundle:nil]autorelease];
```

from the MainWindow screen.

My interface declaration is,

```
#import "SecondWindow.h"

@interface TrainingProject_1AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    SecondWindow *second;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic,retain) SecondWindow *second;

-(IBAction) listTableView:(id) sender;    
@end

// Definition in ".m" file
@synthesize second;

-(IBAction) listTableView:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"event called");
    self.second=[[[SecondWindow alloc]initWithNibName:@" HarbourFront" bundle:nil]autorelease];
}
```

I checked that method is getting called but SecondWindow is not loading.

How can I load SecondWindow ?

Comment: what type of template are you using, view based or navigation based?

Comment: I was selected windowsbased template at first

Comment: what controller you used in window based template?

Comment: UIViewControllerSubclasses i was selected for secondView.xib.

Comment: no, i am not asking that , open your mainwindow.xib file and look in that what controller you are using, e.g they are named as viewcontroller, navigationcontroller etc, its the fourth icon in that file

Comment: Oh sorry @Aman. I am new in iPhone. It is Navigationcontroller.

Comment: check the given below answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
self.second=[[[SecondWindow alloc]initWithNibName:@" HarbourFront" bundle:nil]autorelease];
[self .navigationController pushViewController:self.second animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps you....

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar Just initializing is not enough for a nib to come on screen. It either needs to be pushed on or added to.

Comment: I am getting an error "request for navigationConytoller is somthing not a structure and union".

Comment: open your appdelegate.m file and post the code between the method applicationdidfinishlaunching

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
   
    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    
    return YES;

}

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar It seems you are not using navigation controller. Try to start from navigationBasedApplication template

Comment: Error is removed @Aman. I modified methods. But when i am clicking on Mainscreen buuton function is loading but still second windows is not loading

Comment: Since you did not initialised the  navigationcontroller , thati swhy you are getting the error. You can go step by step , how to create navigation type pp from window based template through given link       http://amaniphone.blog.co.in/2010/10/01/create-a-navigation-type-application-in-using-window-based-template-in-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

just put this line [self.window addSubView:self.second.view]; below the line self.second=[[[SecondWindow alloc]initWithNibName:@" HarbourFront" bundle:nil]autorelease];